# Store field values in a JSON file?

Tags: 8

I'm building a booking calendar module, and want to get back arrival & departure datefields values to highlight reservations on the calendar, passing to a library the variables.

```
public function showCalendarAction() {       
        return [            
            '#attached'=> ['library'=> ['my_booking_calendar/my_booking_calendar.popperjs']],
            '#attached'=> ['library'=> ['my_booking_calendar/my_booking_calendar.bootstrap']],
            '#attached'=> ['library'=> ['my_booking_calendar/my_booking_calendar.bootstrap_year_calendar']],
            '#markup'=>$this->t('<div data-provide="calendar"></div>')
        ];
    }
```

I intended to store all the dates(linked to one hotel/house) in a json file, that I would call in ajax.

If it's a good Drupal 8 practice, how to do this ?

Else, what would be the good way to store and pass the variables to my module library ?

Comment: You could also use a module that creates a JSON data storage type for fields. That way it isn't in a physical file on the server.

Comment: @Kevin : yes, it does make sense. I tried this too, created a view with my fields, and added a REST export in JSON, then I made an Ajax call to get it back. Works pretty good too. I wonder which solution is best practice ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the routing system and create a custom route and output your json within the controller.

After that you can load the url in your ajax call.

module.routing.yml (path_to_module/):

```
  module.content:
  path: '/json-output'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\module\Controller\ModuleController::content'

  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

ModuleController.php (path_to_module/src/Controller/):

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\module\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

/**
 * An example controller.
 */
class ModuleController extends ControllerBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function content() {
    // Load your json content here.
    $json = module_get_json();

    $response = new Response();
    $response->setContent($json);
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return $response;

  }

}
```

Now you can load your json via /json-output. It is also possible to pass variables to the controller via the url.